# Get proxy ping time VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, proxy, ip, ping

I want to ping proxy and get it's ping time (e.g: 41ms).

I tried this code which is working, but i don't get ping time.

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping("216.58.194.51") Then
    MsgBox("Success")
Else
    MsgBox("Failed")
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim Result As Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply
Dim SendPing As New Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
Dim ResponseTime As Long
Try
    Result = SendPing.Send("216.58.194.51")
    ResponseTime = Result.RoundtripTime
        If Result.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
            MsgBox(ResponseTime.ToString) 'ResponseTime is response time
        Else
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("No response")
End Try
```